# Mount a directory outside /Users/... in docker container

Tags: docker

I am trying to mount a directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\NewFolder`) in a docker container at `maven\NewFolder` but I'm getting an error something like this:-

`Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path: mkdir C:\Program Files... : permission denied`

Is it true that only a directory or file within `\Users` can be mounted? How do I mount a directory that's outside `\Users`?

Comment: That is a known limitation in docker (for windows). You cannot mount any directory outside c:/Users

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This process varies with the release and method of installing Docker (e.g. Toolbox is different than Docker for Windows). The Docker for Windows process involves the [steps listed here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives). The key is to go to "Shared drives" in the docker menu and include each drive you want accessible from the Moby VM. Once the Moby VM is restarted with access to these drives, you'll be able to mount them into your container. Note with paths that include spaces, make sure to escape the space or quote your path in your volume command line option.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually running the `docker run...` command dynamically with the directory to be mounted provided by the user. Is there a command line way or silent mode of sharing drives? Do they have to be done by the user only, or can docker prompt this while running a container? Thanks!

Comment: Also, @BMitch,  is the same possible for Docker Toolbox?

Comment: This is a setting done in the Docker install on Windows. The `docker run` command is talking to the docker daemon running inside the VM which has no access to change the settings outside of the VM.

Comment: For Toolbox, you'll need to stop the docker VM, add the share to VirtualBox, and restart it. https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-share-volumes-and-or-drives-using-docker-machine-on-windows-not-beta/20170